# How to pass an array of objects as a redux API request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have an array of objects. I tried passing it directly as a parameter to a API request but was unsuccessful in doing so. Here's my code-

I have an array of objects that looks like this-

```
[0: {startDate: "2019-06-20", endDate: "2019-07-10", 1: {startDate: "2019-06-20", endDate: "2019-07-10"}].
```

The requirement is to pass this array of Objects directly to a redux API request which has to look like this-

```
[{
   "startDate": "2018-04-24",
   "endDate": "2018-12-02",
},
{
   "startDate": "2018-04-24",
   "endDate": "2018-12-02",
}].
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you gave is not valid. I assume your source is an object with keys ´1´, ´2´.
Then you could just use Object.values.
This returns the values of the object as an array.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

Comment: Thanks. It worked when I gave an external key value to the entire array of objects and mapped to their respective key values